# Is it possible to setup MYSQL replication with binlog files generated from server A (which we are considering as Master) to server B

Tags: mariadb, magento2, database-replication, mariasql, mysqlbinlog

We are migrating from the Magento community to **Magento cloud** for one of our projects and we need to access DB for our custom developed CRM.

But unfortunately magento cloud does not support DB replication and they have enabled binlogs and they are not supporting for creating replication user and server id setup, The binlog files can be synced to our CRM server periodically.

Now we want to know whether we can use the binlog files to replicate the database or is there any workaround for doing the same?

We have tried using tunnel setup but the query execution time is more while using tunnel setup which will affect our CRM performance badly.

Also we need to reconfirm whether there are any other possibilities we can try to access the Magento Cloud DB in our CRM without performance lag.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but it may be a little fiddly in the setup you are describing. You can replay the binlogs as relay logs. Have a look at this article for more details:
https://lefred.be/content/howto-make-mysql-point-in-time-recovery-faster/

Specifically, these parts are relevant (you'll need to edit them appropriately):

```
[root@mysql1 mysql]# for i in $(ls /tmp/binlogs/*.0*) 
do  
  ext=$(echo $i | cut -d'.' -f2); 
  cp $i mysql1-relay-bin.$ext; 
done

[root@mysql1 mysql]# ls ./mysql1-relay-bin.0* >mysql1-relay-bin.index
```